# How I can loop navigation property by calling its name in string format?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I have generic update method for my data like this:

```
public virtual void Update(IEnumerable<string> exclude_Property, 
                           IEnumerable<string> include_NavProperty = null,
                           params T[] items)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        _entities.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        foreach (var cn in exclude_Property)
        {
            _entities.Entry(item).Property(cn).IsModified = false;                    
        }
    }
     _entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

I have three parameters in this methods:

1. `exclude_property` - using for a property that I want to exclude while updating
2. `include_NavProperty` - using for in condition of mater detail model, I am passing navigational property name for which I want to edit with master records
3. `items` - for passing model

My problem is, because of generic nature, I don't know the name of navigation property name here, but it has in my `include_NavProperty` parameter in string format.

I want to apply loop on navigation property for marking their item  `EntityState.Modified` for update records in one go.

Comment: May be I am not getting exactly what you're doing but you can always set a property by its name because you can create linq expression using string, etc

Comment: yes I have a property name but in string format